# Cannot import App.jsx in express || Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I am trying to ssr my react app and it's been months trying, but all I get is this error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\ReactApp\client\src\App'
imported from F:\ReactApp\server\express.js
```

at first I tried to require it as so

```
const App = require('../client/src/App')
```

but I got this error :

```
Cannot find module '../client/src/App'
```

so i used module type to use import instead of require as so:

```
import App from '../client/src/App'
```

I checked the similar questions but none have worked!

Directory Structure:
[image: Directory Structure:]
Any Ideas?

Comment: We don't know the directory structure of your project.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `../../client/src/App`?

Comment: @robertklep client and server are in the same directory so isn't ../client/src/App correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I wasn't looking properly.

Comment: client and server are in the same directory does not means that they are the same project, they have different `package.json` file so they are different projects, and `App.jsx` is outside the server project, so it's imposible to import it inside `express.js`

Comment: So I should narrow it to one package, I'll try it thanks!